# SQL Returning False

Tags: php, sql-server

```
$checkQuery = "SELECT Id FROM Events 
                       WHERE Date = '$date' 
                       AND VehId = $vehicleId 
                       AND ((StartTime BETWEEN $timeOut AND $timeIn) 
                       OR (EndTime BETWEEN $timeOut AND $timeIn))";
$checkResults = sqlsrv_query($conn, $checkQuery);
if (sqlsrv_num_rows($checkResults) > 0)
    {
        //do some stuff where the vehicle is already reserved.
    } else { // this always executes.
        var_dump($rowCounts, $date, $vehicleId, $timeOut, $timeIn);
        //insert the new reservation.
    }
```

//Var_dump - bool(false) string(10) "2016-11-01" int(184) float(9.5) float(11)

My SQL query continually returns false, Though I do not get my expects param to be 1 error? Always executes the else statement. Thus, something is wrong in my query, but below is my fiddle that shows it working as expected? My goal is to query the db, if any results come back, it doesn't insert a new record as the vehicle should already be reserved. Any help is appreciated!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a86be/6

```
SELECT Id FROM Events 
     WHERE Date = '2016-11-01' 
     AND VehId = 184 
     AND ((StartTime BETWEEN 9.5 AND 11) 
     OR (EndTime BETWEEN 9.5 AND 11))
```

I'd assume obvious, but I did verify that there is in fact a record in the DB that it should return.

Comment: Unquoted dates being interpreted as mathematical subtraction: 2016 - 11 etc? Please show the content of `$checkQuery`

Comment: I mean the string once interpolation has occurred so we can see the string sent to the server.  (Fix the date issue first)

Comment: Done, and I'll clean up the comments too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php):

> If a forward cursor (the default) or dynamic cursor is used, FALSE is returned.

So you need to specify a different cursor, this is done like this:

```
$checkResults = sqlsrv_query(
    $conn, 
    $checkQuery, 
    array(), 
    array('Scrollable' => 'buffered'));
```